# BouncyCastle equivalent for openssl verify

Tags: openssl

Is there any equivalent in bouncycastle lib for the following openssl command?

```
openssl verify -CAfile cert.pem Attesttation.pem
```

Comment: - Update - 

The mentioned command openssl verifies that the second pem (in my example Attestation.pem) is in the chain with the first pem (cert.pem). 
In other words, it checks that the second pem was signed with the private key related to the public key of the first pem. 

For my purpouse I solve the issue simply using these few lines of code:

X509Certificate attestationCert = ...//get the certificate
X509Certificate rootCert = ...//get the certificate
boolean isValid = attestationCert.verify(root.getPublicKey());